# Two x-axis, one below the other, in a pgfplots groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I have the following plot. I changed the `\addplot table` command by an `\addplot coordinates` just to create a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left,
},
width=7.3cm,
height=7.3cm,
scale only axis,
ymin=-4e-8,ymax=6e-8,
ytick distance=2e-8,
scaled x ticks=false,
change x base,
x SI prefix=nano,
x unit=s,
xlabel={time},
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
]
\nextgroupplot[
ylabel=$ s_{out,R} $,
]
\addplot[blue] coordinates { (0,-3e-8) (100e-9,5e-8) };
\nextgroupplot[ylabel=$ s_{out,I} $,]
\addplot[red] coordinates { (0,-3e-8) (100e-9,5e-8) };
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Question: Is it possible to add an extra x-axis, labeled "frequency [GHz]" and ranging from 0.5 GHz to 3.5 GHz, below the "time [ns]" axis? (something similar to what have been done here [Bell curve with multiple x-axes and annotations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103021/bell-curve-with-multiple-x-axes-and-annotations), or here [How to add multiple x axes with different scaling?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279636/how-to-add-multiple-x-axes-with-different-scaling))

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A groupplot is just an axis really, so you can use the same idea: add a third plot in the group. You just need to change the options regarding xlabels and units a bit. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=1 by 3,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
},
width=7.3cm,
height=7.3cm,
scale only axis,
ymin=-4e-8,ymax=6e-8,
ytick distance=2e-8,
scaled x ticks=false,
change x base,
x SI prefix=nano,
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
]
\nextgroupplot[
ylabel=$ s_{out,R} $,
]
\addplot[blue] coordinates { (0,-3e-8) (100e-9,5e-8) };
\nextgroupplot[ylabel=$ s_{out,I} $,xlabel={time},x unit=s]
\addplot[red] coordinates { (0,-3e-8) (100e-9,5e-8) };

\nextgroupplot[
  axis y line=none,
  axis x line=bottom,
  grid=none,
  xlabel=Frequency,
  x SI prefix=giga,
  x unit=Hz,
  xmin=0.5e9,
  xmax=3.5e9,
  height=0.2cm
]
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(For this screenshot I reduced the `height` just to make it more compact.)

[image: output of code with different height]